Why isn't C++ Lambdas and IOS Blocks Fully Associative?
I am new to IOS programming, and am learning about blocks and lambdas. In my research on blocks and c++ lambdas I read that essentially lambdas can replace blocks because they can do pretty much the same thing.  This appears to be case except for the capture clause and the C++ specific (mutable and throw) optional keywords. I have found some differences that might make a difference - but not sure.  I can create a std::function wrapper type variable (lambda) and assign a block and its equivalent lambda statement(s).  However, if I create a block type variable and attempt to assign a lambda to it - the compile terminates with an error. Why? I'll show the code and the error output below.  Also, I cannot typedef a lambda, I must use a std::function wrapper function type to do the equivalent. Why?

#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <xpc/xpc.h>
#include <dispatch/dispatch.h>

#define SHOW_COMPILE_ERROR
// add comments on next line to see the compile error
#undef SHOW_COMPILE_ERROR


// You cannot create a lambda typedef, but you can create a general purpose
// polymorphic function wrapper from std::wrapper
// e.g. typedef  [] (xpc_object_t) -> void do_custom_message_l_t; is not legal
// but the std::function declaration is legal - why?
typedef std::function<void(xpc_object_t)> do_custom_msg_l_t;
// block typedefs are legal as below
typedef void (^do_custom_msg_b_t)(xpc_object_t);

// create a function declaration with a callback using either
// approaches - the block typedef or the std::function wrapper
// just as well
xpc_object_t build_message(int func,
                           do_custom_msg_b_t&);
xpc_object_t build_message(int func,
                           do_custom_msg_l_t&);

// create a couple of global variables of the block or std::function type
do_custom_msg_b_t do_custom_msg_b;
do_custom_msg_l_t do_custom_msg_l, do_custom_msg_l2;

#if defined(SHOW_COMPILE_ERROR)
do_custom_msg_b_t do_custom_msg_b2;
#endif

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // assign a block to the block type global
    do_custom_msg_b = ^(xpc_object_t custom_message) {
        auto p= xpc_copy_description(custom_message);
        std::cerr << "Custom Message Objects: " << p << std::endl;
        free(p);
    };

    // assign a std::function type a lambda definition - cool.
    // but change the variable to do_custom_msg_b and suddenly there
    // is an error!  So you can assign a lambda definition to a block
    // variable type.  Very weird.
    do_custom_msg_l = [] (xpc_object_t custom_message) {
        auto p= xpc_copy_description(custom_message);
        std::cerr << "Custom Message Objects: " << p << std::endl;
        free(p);
    };

#if defined(SHOW_COMPILE_ERROR)
    // this is not legal - why?, if it is legal to assign a block to a lambda
    // /std::function then why not the other way around?
    do_custom_msg_b2 = [] (xpc_object_t custom_message) {
        auto p= xpc_copy_description(custom_message);
        std::cerr << "Custom Message Objects: " << p << std::endl;
        free(p);
    };
#endif

    // we are now assigning a block to std::function wrapper (lambda)
    // this works just fine . . . weird!
    do_custom_msg_l2  = ^(xpc_object_t custom_message) {
        auto p= xpc_copy_description(custom_message);
        std::cerr << "Custom Message Objects From Blocks Assigned to std::function: " << p << std::endl;
        free(p);
    };

    // in conclusion blocks can be assigned lambda/std::functions but std::functions/lambdas
    // cannot be assigned to block types (typedefs).  So there is a false equivilence between
    // lambdas and blocks

    // here is how lambdas are normally defined and executing them
    // is very easy
    auto mylambda = [] (void *ptr){
        std::cout << "This lambda " << ptr << " is running in thread " << pthread_self() << std::endl;
        sleep(1);
    };
    // here is the block equivalent to the above lambda
    void (^myblock) (void) = ^{
        std::cout << "This block is running in thread " <<  pthread_self() << std::endl;
        sleep(1);
    };
    // call that lambda with its address as a parameter
    mylambda(&mylambda);
    // call the block
    myblock();
    // dispatch the lambda - cool!
    dispatch_async_f(dispatch_get_main_queue(), &mylambda, mylambda);
    // dispatch the block - very cool!
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), myblock);
    // build an object using the block callback
    xpc_object_t msg = build_message(1, do_custom_msg_b);
    // build a message utilizing the lambda call
    msg = build_message(2, do_custom_msg_l);
    // call the lambda variable that was assigned a block
    // this works - very cool!
    msg = build_message(3, do_custom_msg_l2);
#if defined(SHOW_COMPILE_ERROR)
    // nope, this won't even build
    msg = build_message(4, do_custom_msg_b2);
#endif
    dispatch_main();
    return 0;
}


/**
 * @brief build a new message header to be sent to the server
 * @param func The function id of what command to be sent
 * @param do_custom_msg block that can optionally customize this created message
 * @returns the xpc object built
 * @note objects created with this function must be released
 */
xpc_object_t build_message(int func,
                           do_custom_msg_b_t& do_custom_msg)
{
    xpc_object_t msg = xpc_dictionary_create_empty();
    xpc_dictionary_set_uint64(msg, "typ", func);
    xpc_dictionary_set_date(msg, "date", time(nullptr));
    xpc_dictionary_set_uint64(msg, "serno",
                              1);
    if(nullptr != do_custom_msg)
    {
        do_custom_msg(msg);
    }
    return msg;
}

/**
 * @brief build a new message header to be sent to the server
 * @param func The function id of what command to be sent
 * @param do_custom_msg block that can optionally customize this created message
 * @returns the xpc object built
 * @note objects created with this function must be released
 */
xpc_object_t build_message(int func,
                           do_custom_msg_l_t& do_custom_message )
{
    xpc_object_t msg = xpc_dictionary_create_empty();
    xpc_dictionary_set_uint64(msg, "typ", func);
    xpc_dictionary_set_date(msg, "date", time(nullptr));
    xpc_dictionary_set_uint64(msg, "serno",
                              1);
    if(nullptr != do_custom_message)
    {
        do_custom_message(msg);
    }
    return msg;
}

Here are the particulars of my environment:
CLion 2024.1.4.
Apple clang version 15.0.0
2023 Mac Studio running Sonoma 14.6.1
Here is the error message:
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/aarch64/bin/cmake --build "/Users/marksanderson/Projects/codeing tests/cmake-build-debug" --target codeing_tests -j 22
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/codeing_tests.dir/main.cpp.o
FAILED: CMakeFiles/codeing_tests.dir/main.cpp.o 
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++   -g -std=gnu++20 -arch arm64 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.4.sdk -fcolor-diagnostics -MD -MT CMakeFiles/codeing_tests.dir/main.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/codeing_tests.dir/main.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/codeing_tests.dir/main.cpp.o -c '/Users/marksanderson/Projects/codeing tests/main.cpp'
/Users/marksanderson/Projects/codeing tests/main.cpp:59:24: error: assigning to 'do_custom_msg_b_t' (aka 'void (^)(xpc_object_t)') from incompatible type '(lambda at /Users/marksanderson/Projects/codeing tests/main.cpp:59:24)'
    do_custom_msg_b2 = [] (xpc_object_t custom_message) {
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.


Lambdas are a feature of standard C++, not IOS (and your code is also using language features that are not part of standard C++).  "IOS blocks" are (well) IOS specific.  Any interoperability - or lack of - is decided by the implementer of that feature. It is fairly common for platform-specific features to have limited interoperability with standard features - because they offer [perceived or actual] advantages/trade-offs that standardised features do not (and since interoperability is often a key trade-off).

Indeed, my reading on SE and elsewhere was that blocks and lambdas were intended to be fully associative (is that the correct term?).  I found that to be nearly but not fully the case.  The only other facility that I can think of that is similar is static (address found at link time) and dynamic(address found at runtime e.g. function pointers) as far as I remember at this sitting have precisely the same capabilities, but a different approach to get there.  I find it odd that Apple didn't implement this approach with 'full associativity' and wondered why.

To be clear you are using Objective C++ which is separate langue, which merges Objective C and C++ features. This should be used as convenience tool to build bridges between Objective C and C++ libraries (any direction). Operating system is not related to the topic.

Objective C/C++ exists on other platforms/OSs?  If so which one(s)?  Does this environment replicate both GCD and XPC as well?  I'd read that Apple has intended both GCD and XPC (more XPC) to become publicly available such that Linux and BSD environments could implement them w/little or no legal entanglements.  Yes, I've almost become a GCD and XPC fanboy . . .  they certainly have their positive attributes but some changes would have to be made because of mach ports interesting attributes.
